# Append html to text which find with "contains"

Tags: jquery, append, contains

I want to append html to text when find It:

```
 $( "div:contains(']')" ).append("<br>");
```

.. which is wrong, because I want to target this specific text and add html instead of appending html on whole div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to iterate the text nodes that the matching elements have, and in each of those text nodes, locate the "]" in their values. When a text node has this character, split the text node into two, and inject a `<br>` element in between.

Here is some code you could use:

```
$( "div:contains(']')" ).each(function () {
    $(this).contents().each(function () {
        if (this.nodeType !== 3) return; // Only interested in text nodes
        let i; // position of the "]".
        while ((i = this.nodeValue.indexOf("]")) >= 0) {
            $(this).before(this.nodeValue.slice(0, i+1), $("<br>"));
            this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.slice(i+1);
        }
    });
});
```